# Oracle NLS lang issues

Tags: oracle, unicode

I have a weird problem with UTF8 in oracle 10g. The db charset is `US7ASCII`, and I don't know how the vendor system does the inserts (they won't share their code) - I'm just trying to extract data for a report.

I can extract them by returning the fields with `rawtohex(column)`, then using a separate program to convert the hex to unicode in java/c#.

This should work with the driver in any application by changing the registry, but now I'm trying to do this within a query w/SQL*Plus and I get a variety of wrong results.

```
AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII
Keratry, E╠ümile

AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
Keratry, E∩┐╜∩┐╜mile

AMERICAN_AMERICA.US8PC437
Keratry, E■■mile

Correct
Keratry, Émile
```

Dump:

```
Typ=1 Len=39: 75,101,114,97,116,114,121,44,32,69,204,129,109,105,108,101,44,32,9
9,111,109,116,101,32,100,101,44,32,49,56,51,50,45,49,57,48,52,46,32
```

Returning the diacritics correctly has to be possible, but I'm stumped. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the "db charset is AMERICAN.AMERICA.US7ASCII"?  `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII` is a valid `NLS_LANG` but that is a client setting that has nothing to do with the database character set.  The database character set would be in `v$nls_parameters`.  `US7ASCII` would be a valid database character set but that would mean that the database didn't support data outside the 128 7-bit ASCII characters.

Comment: What do you get with NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P15? You are changing the registry, so your client and sqlplus is on WIndows. Can you try setting the environment variable too.

Comment: The DB is US7ASCII. It certainly does support data outside the 128 7-bit characters because the raw hex is in there.

I'm setting the ENV variable only - changing the registry doesn't appear to affect SQL*PLUS: AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P15
Keratry, E┐┐mile

Comment: What data type is the column then, and that is the national character set? Is that dump of the original column value or after you've tried to convert it? `varchar2` columns won't support data outside 7-bit ASCII - though it's possible to put unsupported values in - but `nvarchar2` might. But you've made it sound like this is raw data, which would be strange.

Comment: varchar2, dump of the original column value. There must be some trick to put UTF8 in a 7-bit ASCII varchar2 column, since if you convert it to hex from the raw data and then convert that to unicode it displays properly.

Comment: Is the database on UNIX or Windows, and are you trying the sqlplus on WIndows/Unix. If UNIX, do you get the same results with the different settings for NLS_LANG when you run sqlplus on the same server? I agree with you that just because the db CHARSET is US7ASCII, doesn't prevent extended ASCII being inserted, so the problem is how that "illegal" data is displayed, and that should be a function of NLS_LANG.

Comment: Database is Unix - Trying sql plus on Windows.

Comment: I tried MacOS X with the NLS_LANG as US7ASCII and it works correctly, and it also works correctly running sqlplus in a Cygwin terminal. Doesn't work in SQLDeveloper on my Mac yet, I can't figure out if its the env variable or not.

So is this not possible in windows?

Answer (score 0):

The situation is as follows:

You have an US7ASCII database that stores UTF-8 codes of accented Latin letters. An application stores this data by passing these codes via OCI with `NLS_LANG` set to `.US7ASCII` or not set at all. This is a bad application from Oracle NLS point of view but this is not the question here.

An interesting aspect is that the example data you shown is stored in Unicode denormalized form, in which the accented letter `É` (E acute) is stored as uppercase `U+0045 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E` (e.g. usual ASCII `E`) followed by the Unicode character `U+301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`. This form is correct Unicode but it is less common than the usual combined form, in which `É` is stored as its own combined code `U+00C9 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE`. Some devices may be unable to display the two characters correctly as one accented letter.

To get the data for the report, spool it from SQL*Plus with `NLS_LANG=.US7ASCII` to a file but switch off terminal output. The Command Prompt (US Windows) works in OEM code page 437 (`US8PC437`) and it will not be able to display the UTF-8 codes you get from this spool. When you look at the spooled file in a web browser configured for UTF-8, you should be able to see the data correctly. Notepad or Notepad++ should also be able to show the file correctly (I have checked them on Win10).

Note that setting `NLS_LANG` to anything but `.US7ASCII` will make Oracle attempt to convert from US7ASCII to the character set specified. This will obviously make garbage out of the (incorrectly) stored UTF-8 codes.